# How to identify which `view` has been clicked?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Look at following android code. `IMGS` is a 2 dimensional array of `ImageView`. I am adding `onClickListener` to it in a `for` loop. How to identify which `view` has been clicked ? I dont want to iterate over all the 36 elements using `view.getId();`.

```
private static final Integer[] Icons = {
    R.drawable.r,
    R.drawable.re,
    R.drawable.u,
    R.drawable.et,  
    R.drawable.w,
    R.drawable.ya
};
private ImageView[][] IMGS= new ImageView[6][6];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IMGS[0][0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immg11);



    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
    for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
    {

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(Icons[i]);

    IMGS[i][j].setImageDrawable(d);

     IMGS[i][j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
//HOW TO KNOW WHICH VIEW HAS BEEN CLICKED ?
            }
    });
    }
    }



    }
```

Comment: You might want to use an AbsListView for maintaining those many ImageViews. It's a bit difficult to understand initially, but it'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the `View` argument passed to `onClick(View v)`? It's the view that was clicked.

You can call `v.getId()` to retrieve its id.

> Agreed, but there are 36 elements over which i have to iterate if I use this method. Is there a way to know the indexes of clicked IMGS ?

You can use `setTag()` to save whatever data you want in each view and retrieve it later with `getTag()`.

Comment: Agreed, but there are 36 elements over which i have to iterate if I use this method. Is there any other way to know the indexes of clicked IMGS ?

Comment: yourView.setTag(index) with index as Integer then use getTag() and check the type of your view with instanceof